# how to display the associated form field?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

please help to solve the problem.

There is a table with the data about the user. the table has a related field 'gender'. you want to display a form with a drop-down list to select the gender.

models.py:

```
class Gender(models.Model):     
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, 
        blank=False,
    )   
class UserProfile(User):
    nickname = models.CharField(
        'Отображаемое имя',
        max_length=30, 
        blank=False,
    )
    gender = models.ForeignKey(
        Gender,
        #default=1,
        null=True,
    )
```

views.py:

```
def personal_data_page(request):
    entry_user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user_ptr_id__exact=request.user.id)    
    form = PersonalDataForm(instance=entry_user_profile)    

    t = loader.get_template('personal_data_page.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
        'form': form,
    })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

forms.py:

```
class PersonalDataForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            'nickname', 
            'gender',  
        )
```

personal_data_page.html:

```
<div class="cell">
    <label class="label">{{ form.gender.label }}</label>

    {{ form.gender }}

    {{ form.gender.errors }}
</div>
```

the problem is that the line outputs

> 1

. and I need to output is something like:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Male</option>
    <option value="2">Female</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you make a `UserProfile` model with a `ForeignKey` to a Gender table? Just simply include the gender in the UserProfile.

And what are you looking for is called a `choice_field`.

Here is an example: [ChoiceField in Django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077840/choicefield-in-django-model)

And here is the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#field-choices.

Also, here is some docs about using a widget with choices: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

**EDIT**

If you realy want to keep the Gender table:

```
class PersonalDataForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            'nickname', 
            'gender',  
        )
        widgets = {'gender': forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = 
                                                    Gender.objects.all())}
```

, assuming that you have defined `__unicode__` for `Gender`

See more here:

1. [Specifying widget for model form extra field (Django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097825/specifying-widget-for-model-form-extra-field-django)
2. [Django, ModelChoiceField() and initial value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336900/django-modelchoicefield-and-initial-value)

Comment: I need to do through foreignKey, but not through the choices

Comment: made an edit for you. PS: Please learn English at a basic level if you want to be a part of the international community and expect to receive answers in English. We need do understand your question first of all