# ModelChoiceField with Django Forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm stuck with Django and I would like to learn more and more on this framework. I read some tutorials (English and French tutorials) and as I'm beginning, I don't find what I want.

I have a `forms.py file` in my app directory :

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django import forms

class BirthCertificateForm (forms.Form) :

#   rowid = forms.IntegerField()  # rowid primary key
#   numero_acte = forms.IntegerField()  # Form number
    date_acte = forms.DateField('%d/%m/%Y')    # Form date
    heure_acte = forms.TimeField('%H:%M:%S')   # Form hour
    nom = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label=u"Nom")   # Lastname
    prenom = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label=u"Prénom")   # Firstname
    sexe = forms.  # <== I would like to have the choice between 'M' or 'F'
```

And this is my `views.app` file :

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from BirthCertificate.forms import BirthCertificateForm

# Create your views here.

def BirthCertificateAccueil(request) :
    # Fonction permettant de créer la page d'accueil de la rubrique Acte de Naissance 

    #Cherche le fichier html accueil et le renvois
    template = loader.get_template('accueil.html') 
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request))


def BirthCertificateCreationAccueil(request) :
     # Fonction permettant de créer la page de création du formulaire de la partie : Acte de Naissance 

     template = loader.get_template('creation_accueil.html')
     return HttpResponse(template.render(request))

def BirthCertificateForm(request) :
    # Fonction permettant de créer le formulaire Acte de Naissance et le remplissage

    if request.method == 'POST' :
        form = BirthCertificateForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            numero_acte = form.cleaned_data["Numero de l'acte"]
            nom = form.cleaned_data['Nom']
            prenom = form.cleaned_data['Prenom']

    return render_to_response(request, 'birthform.html', {'form' : form})
```

1) I would like to have the choice between 2 options in sexe field. The user have to select `M` or `F`. I think I have to use `ModelChoiceField` but I don't know how I can use this function.

2) Other question : When the use submits the form, the database which is behind is updated right ? So I have to specify the `rowid` somewhere or it's automatically added ?

Thank you so much !

Comment: Do you have model to which that form is related? And also almost anything you can find in [Django awesome docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/)!!!

Comment: @vishes_shell No, my models.py file is empty. Is it necessary to have one ? The tutorial that I'm following doesn't specify a model file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ModelChoiceField is for, well, choices that come from models. If you don't want models (and I don't understand what you're doing with your data if you don't, but never mind) then you just use [ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield).

```
sexe = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('M', 'Mâle'), ('F', 'Femelle'))
```

Comment: Thank you to your answer. With my form data, I would like to replace some variables in a text for example. I don't write a model file because the tutorial that I'm following don't specify a model.py file. But if it's necessary, I will make one.

Comment: Even touch of french, i like it!:)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a model to store gender information. All you need is simply CharField with choices.

Please have a look at the example in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8077907/4890586