# Django: choose 'company' from company model, if company not present create one

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a use case where in UserProfile model, user details are stored. One of the field is user_company_name.

```
class UserProfile(BaseModel):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user_company_name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
```

Instead of a `CharField` I want the field to be a ChoiceField, having drop down of the Company (names) currently present in the database. If the current company of the user is not present in the dropdown I plan to give the user an option to add his or her company to the DB.
Suppose I have a Company model as such:

```
class Company(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

What should be my Field Choice in the UserProfile model for `user_company_name` field.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077840/choicefield-in-django-model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ChoiceField in Django model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077840/choicefield-in-django-model)

Comment: You could use `try: .... except:` to test if there is the company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't just add `ForeignKey` to `UserProfile` model? Example below.

```
class UserProfile(BaseModel):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user_company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need ForeignKey for this field 
`user_company_name`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey
 read this doc

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreign key in the models for user_company and in forms use ChoiceField to get a drop down.

Check the code below:-

In models:-

```
class UserProfile(BaseModel):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
user_company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

In Forms:-

```
user_company = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Company.objects.all())
```